# Change text color and background color using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have serval buttons on this web page to change the

color and background color. 
Here are the actual text and CSS file plus the javascript

```js
function changeForeground() {
  var div = document.getElementById("foreground").className = "colorA";
}

function changeBackground() {
  var div = document.getElementById("background").className = "backgroundB";
}
```

```css
.colorA {
  color: #4581cf;
}
.colorB {
  color: #B7E2FF;
}
.backgroundA {
  background-color: #4581cf;
}
.backgroundB {
  background-color: #B7E2FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="backgroundA">
  <div id="foreground" class="colorB">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>

Foreground
<INPUT type="button" Value="A" class="colorA" id="button1" onclick="changeForeground()" ;>
<INPUT type="button" Value="B" class="colorB" id="button2" onclick="changeForeground()" ;>Background
<INPUT type="button" Value="C" class="backgroundA" id="button3" onclick="changeBackground()" ;>
<INPUT type="button" Value="D" class="backgroundB" id="button4" onclick="changeBackground()" ;>
```

right now I can only change the text color by typing the actually class such as "colorA" and "backgroundB" after I get the element by Id to change the color. 
but what I am trying to do is in the javascript function, how can I change the text color based on which button I click. 
What I mean is after I get the element by Id such as "foreground", how can I change its current class (colorB) to the class (colorA) if I just clicked button A

Comment: Have the different buttons' `onclick` handlers either call a different function, or pass different parameters to that function. (`onclick` handlers don't have to be a single function call; they can be any JS code.)

Answer (score 4):

Pass the class name to the `function` and use it

```js
function changeForeground(cls){
  var div = document.getElementById("foreground").className=cls;
}
                                        
function changeBackground(cls){
  var div = document.getElementById("background").className=cls;
}
```

```css
.colorA{
      color: #4581cf;
    }

    .colorB{
      color: #B7E2FF;
    }

    .backgroundA{
      background-color: #4581cf;
    }

    .backgroundB{
      background-color: #B7E2FF;
    }
```

```html
<div id="background" class="backgroundA">
   <div id="foreground" class="colorB">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
   </div>
</div>

Foreground 
    <INPUT type="button" Value="A" class="colorA" id="button1" onclick ="changeForeground('colorA')";>
    <INPUT type="button" Value="B" class="colorB" id="button2" onclick ="changeForeground('colorB')";>

Background
    <INPUT type="button" Value="C" class="backgroundA" id="button3" onclick ="changeBackground('backgroundA')";>
    <INPUT type="button" Value="D" class="backgroundB" id="button4" onclick ="changeBackground('backgroundB')";>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function changeForeground()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("foreground").style.color = "#4581cf";
}

function changeBackground()
{
    var div =    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundColor = "#B7E2FF";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery

```
     function changeForeground()
        {var div = $(#foreground).css('color' :'#4581cf');}
```